# Numpy Dimensions: Multiplications with scalar/matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a variable `X` which can either be a scalar or an array. In either case, I want to extent `X` with

```
y = np.array([0.5, 1.5])
```

If `X` is a scalar, that will be

```
(X*y).sum()
```

If `X` is a matrix, say of 2 dimensions , I want to do

```
(X[..., np.newaxis]*y[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, ...]).sum()
```

I'm creating `y` with

```
try:
    ndim = X.ndim
except AttributeError:
    ndim = 0
y = np.array([0.5, 1.5], ndmin=ndim+1)
```

which allows me to do the multiplication with `X[..., np.newaxis]*y`: `y` is now independent of the shape of `X` in my calculations. However, I still need to do `X[..., np.newaxis]` if `X` is a matrix, and only `X` if it is a scalar.

How can I manipulate `X` at the start of my code such that I can do

```
(X*y).sum()
```

and similar operations later on, no matter whether `X` was a matrix or not?

Comment: @dbliss Right, I assumed this question to be so basic that the code was actually used for demonstration of what I want, as opposed to having a running example. But I fixed that, as I'm always grateful for snarky comments from newcomers to SO.

Comment: yeah, i'm a snarky dude, but i'm not really a newcomer.  what do you mean you want to "extent" `X`?

Comment: and why do you need to do `(X*y).sum()` later on?  why isn't it OK to do `(X[..., np.newaxis]*y[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, ...]).sum()` when `X` is a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `np.newaxis` in `y` are not needed. You can obtain the same result without them. For the `X`, I guess you can do the following:

```
if type(X) == np.ndarray:
    result = (X[..., np.newaxis] * y).sum()
else:
    result = (X * y).sum()
```

If you want to generalize it for more than one operation, you can just add one line somewhere in the code:

```
X = X[..., np.newaxis] if type(X) == np.ndarray else X
```

And later just use `(X * y).sum()` since it will work both with `X = number` and `X = ndarray`.

As for the `y`, you don't need to add number dimensions, numpy has [smart broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for multiplications.

A full example:

```
>>> x1 = 5
>>> x2 = np.random.rand(3,3)
>>> y  = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
>>> (x1 * y).sum() # works fine
>>> (x2[..., np.newaxis] * y).sum() # also works fine
```